# How to expose informatica as a web service for salesforce to connect and pass data?

Tags: web-services, salesforce, etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

We have salesforce where in we need to pass Id field for informatica , once this Id field is passed, informatica will fetch records from database based on the Id. How can we expose informatica power centre as a web service for salesforce to call

Comment: Hi - have you read the Informatica API documentation? If so, what is your specific question?

Comment: like salesforce can create rest api or soap api. how do we create webservices in informatica, where salesforce can call this informatica and pass data?

Comment: “how do we create webservices in Informatica” is asking for a tutorial on a large and complex topic and therefore is highly unlikely to get an answer here. As I said in my previous comment, you need to read the comprehensive tutorials and examples that Informatica provides, try it out for yourself and then, if necessary, come back to this site to ask a question about a specific issue you are facing

Comment: Exposing a service for SF to call, securing it, paying for hosting(?) might be work, I don't know enough about Infa to comment. Typically you'd do it other way around, have Infa poll SF for changes. Fetch records created(?) today or since last run time variable, have it run even every 15 minutes, job done? Or read if Infa can subscribe to SF "platform events" (cometd, bayeux protocol), that way SF publishes a message without explicitly calling Infa server. In a way Infa still polls for changes but it's near realtime, not scheduled

Answer (score 1):

Typically this would've been done as part of the Informatica process to send a request to SF, get the Id and use it for further processing.

If the flow needs to be initiated by SF, you can expose workflow as a webservice and have SF make the request to PowerCenter. Rather a rare scenario, and not really recommended.

Check your requirements, check docs and tutorials, try building the solution, let us know if some help is required.